# Bash Shell: update order of students in a file by updating their mark

Tags: unix, awk

So I have 2 files that have a very similar format:

file **average_grades**

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Average_Grade
323 Dospinescu Arianna 10.00
326 Balan Ionut 9.87
327 Balan Teodor-Raul 9.80
329 Popescu Iulian-Gabriel 9.56
317 Tabarcea Andreea 9.48
365 Negruzzi Marian 9.23
398 Acatrinei Andrei 9.00
365 Popescu Anca-Maria 8.76
```

and file **summer_marks**

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Summer_Grades
326 Balan Ionut 10 10 10 10 10
327 Balan Teodor-Raul 9 8 7 6 5
329 Popescu Iulian-Gabriel 4 5 6 7 8
365 Negruzzi Marian 4 5 6 7 8
398 Acatrinei Andrei 7 7 7 7 7
387 Popescu Anca-Maria 1 2 3 4 5
317 Tabarcea Andreea 9 8 7 6 5
323 Dospinescu Arianna 9 10 9 10 9
```

I want to write a shell that gets the 2 files as parameters and that updates the marks in **average_grades** as follows: calculate the average of the 5 marks each student got in the summer, then the average between this result and the already existing average grade(on the last column in **average_grades**); update the last_colum and re-sort **average_grades** by the new values on the last column. How can I do that? Note: It is guaranteed that the ID of each student is unique

I have tried using `awk` but failed. I wanted to iterate through every line in **summer_marks**, calculate the average for each 5 marks and store these values in an array, then again iterate through each line in **average_grades**, calculate the new average and update last column, then re-sort.

Comment: Please do add 2 things in your post. 1- your failed attempts in code. 2- your expected output. Kindly do let us know once post edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your description is very close. You will iterate through `summer_marks` (using `NR==FNR` as your rule condition) and average the last 5 grades. Then you will loop over `average_grades` and add the average to the current average and divide by 2 (or weight it however you like). You can use `NR>FNR` for the second rule condition. You can use ID as the index for your array and then match that to the index in `average_grades` to keep the indexing correct. So long as `average_grades` is currently in the sort-order you want, there is no need to re-sort, e.g.

```
awk 'NR==FNR && FNR>1 {
        n=0
        sum=0
        for(i=4;i<=NF;i++) {
            sum+=$i
            n++;
        }
        avg=sum/n
        id[$1]=avg
    }
    NR>FNR {
        if($1 in id) {
            $NF+=id[$1]
            $NF/=2
        }
        print $0
    }
' summer_marks average_grades
```

**Example Output**

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Average_Grade
323 Dospinescu Arianna 9.7
326 Balan Ionut 9.935
327 Balan Teodor-Raul 8.4
329 Popescu Iulian-Gabriel 7.78
317 Tabarcea Andreea 8.24
365 Negruzzi Marian 7.615
398 Acatrinei Andrei 8
365 Popescu Anca-Maria 7.38
```

If you want to sort-descending by the new averages, then you can pipe the results to `| sort -k4r` and that would produce

**Sorted Output**

```
ID First_Name Last_Name(s) Average_Grade
326 Balan Ionut 9.935
323 Dospinescu Arianna 9.7
327 Balan Teodor-Raul 8.4
317 Tabarcea Andreea 8.24
398 Acatrinei Andrei 8
329 Popescu Iulian-Gabriel 7.78
365 Negruzzi Marian 7.615
365 Popescu Anca-Maria 7.38
```

Comment: I was reading what he wrote, and thinking -- "that should work"! I suspect he may have been hung up on skipping the 1st row when averaging, or in mapping the ID as the array index to keep the averages straight. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much! Nonetheless, sorting is a must afterwards. Average_grades is in the right order, but what you did to its last column will affect the averages, thus the order

Comment: Yes, I was a little confused on the need to resort until I looked at how `average_grades` was sorted originally. Then then the part of your question mentioning re-sort made sense to put `average_grades` back in sort-order after the averages were updated. Good luck with your scripting.

Comment: `sort -k4r` will fail if there can be an average of 10 or more as it's sorting alphabetically rather than numerically and `sort -k4rn` will fail because the column header would come out after all the data lines. Change `print $0` to `print (FNR>1), $0` and then `awk '...'  summer_marks average_grades | sort -k1,1n -k5,5rn | cut -d' ' -f2-` will preserve the header as the first row while sorting the data on the required field without relying on the last field of the header line possibly coincidentally sorting in the order you want.

Comment: Thanks Ed. Yes ideally I wanted to just `head` the first row and then `tail | sort -k4nr` rows 2 on. I had a bit of trouble with your suggestion, no 5th field the `-k5,5rn` scrambled things a bit.